# How to load httpfs duckdb extension

Tags: r, amazon-s3, dbi, duckdb

I am trying to load httpfs duckdb extension to access parquet file on s3 but it looks like it cannot load even though the file  httpfs.duckdb_extension is in the directory

```
 library(DBI)
 library(duckdb)
 con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
 DBI::dbExecute(con, "INSTALL httpfs")
```

[1] 0

```
DBI::dbExecute(con, "LOAD httpfs")
```

Erreur : rapi_execute: Failed to run query
Error: IO Error: Extension "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\R\data\R\duckdb.duckdb\extensions\v0.9.2\windows_amd64_rtools\httpfs.duckdb_extension" could not be loaded: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

Comment: The extension is available at http://extensions.duckdb.org/v0.9.2/windows_amd64_rtools/httpfs.duckdb_extension.gz . Can you please try installing it again?

Comment: I installed it again, load httpfs is still not working . for fts extension it works fine : DBI::dbExecute(con, "LOAD 'fts';")

Comment: Thanks. Could you then please try to download the extension from the link above and install it locally? See the instructions here: https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/working_with_extensions.html#installing-extensions-from-an-explicit-path

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried : INSTALL 'path/to/httpfs.duckdb_extension'  INSTALL works fine but the LOAD does not .

Comment: related to https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/8243 ?